Como hacer el login de un usuario custom en django
Estoy con django y cree un usuario custom para usar de user, ese es el model

A la hora de registrarse funciona todo bien pero a la hora del login no consigo logear, las credenciales siempre son erroneas esta es mi vista:

Este es mi form:

En mi settings añadi esta linea pero sigue sin funcionar


El código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Prueba también añadiendo, a tu settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'nombre_app.CustomUser'

Luego de eso asegurate de correr las migraciones e intenta de nuevo.
También puedes encontrar más información acá:
Documentación Oficial de Django, Autenticación Personalizada
